# MapPoint ZoomTo

Tags: c#, arcmap

So I am making an add in in C# for **arcmap**
and I got this :

```
MapPoint myPoint = new MapPoint(500, 500, spatialRef);

MyMap.ZoomTo(myPoint);
```

from this website:
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/13749-how-to-Zoom-to-point

Since there isn't much information to find on the internet and I am fairly new to ARCGIS I cant figure out my problems that easily so the questions might sound dumb.

I get an error at `spatialRef`. The `spatialRef` should be replaced by something but I have no idea what. I also have no idea what to replace `MyMap` with, and I cant figure out what reference I am missing at `MapPoint` since I also get an error at that part.

Can someone please explain me what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first define your map by:

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Map MyMap;
```

then define your spatial reference

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.SpatialReference _spatialReference = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.SpatialReference(4269);
```

the 4269 is the Well Known ID (WKID) of the GCS_North_American_1983 spatial reference/coordinate system. You can choose any WKID. Just choose a number from [here](http://gis.boemre.gov/arcgis/sdk/rest/gcs.html).

Then define your map point

```
MapPoint myPoint = new MapPoint(500, 500, _spatialReference );
```

and perform ZoomTo

```
MyMap.ZoomTo(myPoint);
```

Comment: I am getting an error at the Client parts and MyMap doesn't exist in the current content

Comment: Sorry, I wrote myMap instead of MyMap. Try now.

Comment: As for error at client parts, Please install ESRI API for WPF (if you are working in C#) in your system and then add service reference of ESRI.ArcGIS.Client and ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources and ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit to your project

Answer (score 0):

It should be replaced with object of [SpatialReference](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/silverlight/apiref/topic712.html) class, like `new SpatialReference()`. You also can pass to the constructor [WKID](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp/pcs.htm).

Comment: What should be between the ()?

Comment: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp/pcs.htm

Comment: I dont get that link?